# Add data from CSV to a SQL Server table column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, csv

I want to add data from a CSV file into a column of a table in SQL Server. My code is running but data not reaching the column.

```
private void btCode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //string constring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=*******;Integrated Security=True";
        string filepath = "C:\\code.csv";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;

        foreach (string Code in value)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Code));
        }
```

while:

```
while ( !sr.EndOfStream )
{
            value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if(value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
}

SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(sc.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
bc.DestinationTableName = "CodesTable";
bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
sc.Open();
bc.WriteToServer(dt);
bc.Close();
sc.Close();
```

Comment: How many rows are in your file ? I presume you've determined that the bulk copy if failing ? (You've read your file and your data table is ok?)

Comment: If you have >= 2 rows in the csv file why are you calling sr.ReadLine() only once in btCode_Click ??

Answer (score 0):

Y dont you try with reading CSV directly using OleDbConnection and then load it to datatable using OleDbDataAdapter.

secondly you can add try catch block to see if its throwing some exception.